# Is it possible to use RPI as a mass storage device?

Tags: pi-3

I am trying to connect my Raspberry3 to a "Linux-Based" device. I want the RPI to get detected as a Mass Storage Device. Is this possible?

Comment: You want to connect your Pi to another PC, and use your Pi like it was an USB flash drive?

Comment: I will connect the RPI to another device (like a phone/car infotainment system, but not another PC). And I want RPI to get detected as a USB Flash Drive

Answer (score 1):

Only the Raspberry Pi Zero , Zero W , Model A and Compute Module can act as USB device. The Raspberry Pi 3 Model B can **not** act as USB device. This is a hardware limitation which cannot be worked around in software.

Here is a guide for the Pi Zero using ConfigFS :

http://isticktoit.net/?p=1383

Comment: Oh! Is there any other device that you recommend for the purpose stated above?